# Nvidia driver error - CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: cuda, nvidia-docker

I am trying to call Laia - a deeplearning toolkit for HRW : https://github.com/jpuigcerver/Laia

This is the code I have:

```
INPUT_DIR=`pwd`/RecognitionHand/dir_input
OUTPUT_DIR=`pwd`/RecognitionHand/dir_output
CHAR_TRANSCRIBE_FILE=char.txt
WORD_TRANSCRIBE_FILE=word.txt

rm $INPUT_DIR/filelist/filenames.lst

ls -d -1 $INPUT_DIR/images/* > $INPUT_DIR/filelist/filenames.lst

COMMAND="decode --batch_size 20  --log_level info   --symbols_table \
    $INPUT_DIR/symbtable/symbs.txt \
    $INPUT_DIR/model/model_htr.t7 \
    $INPUT_DIR/filelist/filenames.lst> $OUTPUT_DIR/$CHAR_TRANSCRIBE_FILE";


# local volumes mapped to the docker volumes
OPTS=( -u $(id -u):$(id -g) );
[ -d "/home" ]  && OPTS+=( -v /home:/home );
[ -d "/mnt" ]   && OPTS+=( -v /mnt:/mnt );
[ -d "/media" ] && OPTS+=( -v /media:/media );
[ -d "/tmp" ]   && OPTS+=( -v /tmp:/tmp );


# call the GPU docker for transcribing
docker run --rm -t "${OPTS[@]}" laia:active \
  bash -c "cd $(pwd) && PATH=\" .:$PATH:\$PATH\" laia-$COMMAND";
```

The last docker command refers to nvidia-docker and I am getting this strange error:

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-918/cutorch/lib/THC/THCGeneral.c line=66 error=35 

: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
[2020-01-02 14:43:45  WARN] /opt/torch/share/lua/5.1/laia/util/base.lua:39: Optional lua module "cutorch" was not found!
[2020-01-02 14:43:45  WARN] /opt/torch/share/lua/5.1/laia/util/base.lua:39: Optional lua module "cunn" was not found!
[2020-01-02 14:43:45  WARN] /opt/torch/share/lua/5.1/laia/util/base.lua:39: Optional lua module "laia.util.cudnn" was not found!
[2020-01-02 14:43:45  WARN] /opt/torch/share/lua/5.1/laia/util/base.lua:39: Optional lua module "laia.ImageDistorter" was not found!
/opt/torch/bin/luajit: /opt/torch/lib/luarocks/rocks/laia/scm-1/bin/laia-decode:16: attempt to call field 'registerOptions' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /opt/torch/lib/luarocks/rocks/laia/scm-1/bin/laia-decode:16: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00405d50
```

Why is this happening? Has someone met a similar error when running nvidia-docker please?

Comment: "CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version" is an extremely common error, usually related to have too old a driver installed for the CUDA version you are trying to use. If you search on that exact error, you will find a lot of information on how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

means that the nvidia driver for your system is not compatible to the runtime inside the docker image you download. You have to (at least) match those versions.
Another important thing is to check what is the necessary cuda runtime for the tool that you want to use. Assuming that you followed the necessary version and downloaded the correct docker image, you will need to update your system nvidia driver to match the docker image then.